# Can the edges in ${\overrightarrow{K}_n}$ be directed in such way that there are no circuits?

Tags: graph-theory

${\overrightarrow{K}_n}$ is a directed complete graph. To my understanding, this is known as a complete digraph (correct?).

Since every pair of distinct vertices is connected by a pair of unique edges, there surley must always exists a circuit, no?

Thanks!

${\textbf{Edit:}}$

I think what I'm looking for is a transitive tournament and not a complete digraph.

Comment: This is called a tournament sometimes. If $a\rightarrow b$ and $b\rightarrow c$ then in order to not have a circuit we require $a\rightarrow c$. So the only way in which there is no circuit is if your graph is a total order. So basically the "only" counterexample is when you label the vertices $1$ to $n$ and direct edges from the small number to the big one.

Comment: @Yorch Definitions vary, but usually, a tournament is different from a complete digraph. A tournament always has exactly one of the edges $\{v \to w, w \to v\}$ for every pair $v,w$; the complete digraph has both. ....I suppose that if we're asking "can the edges be directed in such a way that there are no circuits", we're looking at the tournament and not the usual notion of a complete digraph, though.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I think my very sparse knowledge led me to confusion. I mean, if it were a complete digraph, then there must always exists a circuit (due to even degrees for every vertex). I think what I'm looking for is a transitive tournament  which I believe is a directed complete graph without any circuits. What do you think?

Comment: @Yorch Thank you! I think that I'm looking for a transitive tournament, since it they fulfill the conditions you mention. What do you think?

Comment: yes that's exactly what you need. But transitive tournaments are very limited, they just consist of ordering the nodes in some way  left to right and make all the arrows always got to the right.

Comment: @Yorch awesome! Thank you for your help!

Comment: glad to help.${}$